# Retrieve all elements in Google Trends Data using selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-trends

I am trying to write a Python program to gather data from Google Trends (GT)- specifically, I want to automatically open URLs and access the specific values that are displayed in the title.
I have written the code and i am able to scrape data successfully. But i compare the data returned by code and one present in the url, the results are only partially returned. 
For e.g. in the below image, the code returns the first title "Manchester United F.C. • Tottenham Hotspur F.C." But the actual website has 4 results "Manchester United F.C. • Tottenham Hotspur F.C. , International Champions Cup, Manchester
     ". 
[google trends image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXpbh.png)

[screenshot output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKxOl.png)

We have currently tried all all possible locate elements in a page but we are still unable to fund a fix for this. We didn't want to use scrapy or beautiful soup for this

```
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver

    links=["https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=DE&category=s"] 

    for link in links:
        Title_temp=[]
        Titile=''
        seleniumDriver = r"C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe" 
        chrome_options = Options()
        brow = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=seleniumDriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
        try:
            brow.get(link) ## getting the url
            try:
                content = brow.find_elements_by_class_name("details-top")
                for element in content:
                    Title_temp.append(element.text)    
                Title=' '.join(Title_temp)
            except:
                Title=''       
            brow.quit()

        except Exception as error:
            print error
            break

    Final_df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Title': Title_temp
        })
```

Comment: I am able to get the complete text `['Emanuel Buchmann • Tour de France • Enrico Poitschke', 'Alexander Zverev • Hamburg', 'Nairo Quintana • Tour de France • Col du Galibier • Race stage • France', 'Germany', 'Alexander Zverev • Jan-Lennard Struff • Nicolás Jarry • Tennis • Rothenbaum tournament', 'Hertha BSC • Bundesliga • Fenerbahçe S.K. • Berlin • Ante Čović', 'Tour de France • Tony Martin • Luke Rowe', 'Tottenham Hotspur F.C. • Manchester United F.C. • Manchester • International Champions Cup', 'Am Rothenbaum • Tennis • Hamburg • Association of Tennis Professionals']]` with your code.

Comment: @supputuri: Thanks for your reply. Did you run our code without any change? Because when we run we are not getting complete list

Comment: Let me post the code that I ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, data is retrieved from an API endpoint you can call direct. I show how to call and then extract only the title (note more info is returned other than just title from API call). You can explore the breadth of what is returned (which includes article snippets, urls, image links etc) [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=3753d5fb96d444cfb5ecd3ce6b1509c9).

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/api/realtimetrends?hl=en-GB&tz=-60&cat=s&fi=0&fs=0&geo=DE&ri=300&rs=20&sort=0')
data = json.loads(r.text[5:])
titles = [story['title'] for story in data['storySummaries']['trendingStories']]
print(titles)
```

Comment: @Thanks QHarr. This is really cool. This is simple and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which printed all the information.

```
url = "https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=DE&category=s"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'details-top')))
Title_temp = []
try:
    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("details-top")
    for element in content:
        Title_temp.append(element.text)
    Title=' '.join(Title_temp)
except:
    Title=''
print(Title_temp)
driver.close()
```

Here is the output.

> ['Hertha BSC • Fenerbahçe S.K. • Bundesliga • Ante Čović • Berlin', 'Eintracht Frankfurt • UEFA Europa League • Tallinn • Estonia • Frankfurt', 'FC Augsburg • Galatasaray S.K. • Martin Schmidt • Bundesliga • Stefan Reuter', 'Austria national football team • FIFA • Austria • FIFA World Rankings', 'Lechia Gdańsk • Brøndby IF • 2019–20 UEFA Europa League • Gdańsk', 'Alexander Zverev • Hamburg', 'Julian Lenz • Association of Tennis Professionals • Alexander Zverev', 'UEFA Europa League • Diego • Nairo Quintana • Tour de France']

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for sharing the code. But we are still not getting the results completely.

Comment: We also tried the following 1)used the latest chrome driver , 2)tried firefox driver 3)tried using proxy but not luck

Comment: Can you please share the selenium, driver, browser versions.

Comment: We tried the following combinations : 1) Browser :Chrome version 76, Driver: ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68
2) Browser: Chrome version 75, Driver: ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140 3) Browser : Firefox 68.0  driver: geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64.zip 4) selenium version :2.53.6

Comment: what about python version?

Comment: Thanks for your help. We were able to fix the issue. we found an alternative. We are now parsing the entire inner html and cleaning it try:
            elements = brow.find_elements_by_class_name('details-top')
            for element in elements:
                html_text = parse_html(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
                title_temp.append(html_text.replace('share','').strip())

Comment: Glad, that you are able to resolve it. But, still thinking what might be the reason for this odd behavior ...hmm

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find a fix for this. We had to scrape data from inner html and then do some bit of data cleaning to get required records

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#html parser
def parse_html(content):    
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from bs4.element import Comment
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    text_elements = soup.findAll(text=True)
    tag_blacklist = ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]','img']
    clean_text = []
    for element in text_elements:
        if element.parent.name in tag_blacklist or isinstance(element, Comment):
            continue
        else:
            text_ = element.strip()
            clean_text.append(text_)
    result_text = " ".join(clean_text)
    result_text = result_text.replace(r'[\r\n]','')
    tag_remove_pattern = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
    result_text = tag_remove_pattern.sub('', result_text)
    result_text = re.sub(r'\\','',result_text)
    return result_text

seleniumDriver = r"./chromedriver.exe" 
chrome_options = Options()
brow = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=seleniumDriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
links=["https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=DE&category=s"]
title_temp = []
for link in links:
    try:
        brow.get(link)
        try:
            elements = brow.find_elements_by_class_name('details-top')
            for element in elements:
                html_text = parse_html(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
                title_temp.append(html_text.replace('share','').strip())
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
        time.sleep(1)
        brow.quit()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        break
Final_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Title': title_temp
    })

print(Final_df)
```

Comment: I get an empty dataframe when running this.